# matplotlib format_coord text is wrapping

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using Matplotlib's Axes.format_coord to show the y-coords of several curves at the same time, and the text is long enough that it wraps to a new line, which is only partially visible. Here's an image of the bottom edge of a figure showing the issue. Is there a way to increase the length of the space allocated for the format_coord text? Thanks for any help.

[image: Bottom edge of figure showing issue.]

Edit: I'm running on Mac OS X High Sierra, using python 3.6 and matplotlib 2.1.1, and the issue occurs when running the code with IDLE as well as from the command line. Here's a bit of code that creates the same kind of problem:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from math import pi, sin

N = 30
x = [n/N for n in range(5*N)]
y = [sin(n*pi/N) for n in range(5*N)]

ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.format_coord = lambda x, y : 'the x-coordinate = ' + format(x, '1.4f') + ', ' + \
                                'the y-coordinate = ' + format(y, '1.4f')
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

In preparing this sample, I noticed that stretching the figure window to make it wider does not increase the space available for the coordinate text. Similarly, making the window narrower does not reduce the available space, and the coordinate text gets chopped off at the right edge of the window.

Comment: I cannot reproduce using the TkAgg backend, so maybe you want to use that one instead.

Comment: Thx - I've confirmed that TkAgg solves the issue for me too. It has a fuzzier appearance (poorer resolution) though, so I still have interest in trying to find a solution for the macOS backend.

Comment: The macos backend uses Cocoa. It is compiled at setup and [hardcodes a width of the message box of 300 pixels](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/96ac97c0bd26bcf5ec9267392b580c24e0a34bb2/src/_macosx.m#L1712). I'm not sure if it is possible to change that at runtime or not.

Comment: Thx very much for digging that up - looks like I'll have to live with it or check out other backends. Is there a way to submit a change request to have that rectangle width track with the window width?

Comment: You may use the [Matplotlib issue tracker](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues) to report issues or ask for desirable features.